# Strange undefined method model_name issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I want to edit my record in the database with nested attributes. In my controller I have:

```
def edit
  @chocolate = Chocolate.new.kinds.find_by_id(params[:chocolate_id])
end
```

and in my `edit.html.erb` I have:

```
form_for @chocolate do |choco|
```

but it gives me the next error:

```
undefined method model_name issue
```

I cannot understand why it gives me such error. Any options?

Comment: Remove .new from Chocolate.new.kinds.find_by_id(params[:chocolate_id])

Answer (score 0):

Those methods aren't really made to be mixed together in that way.

I'm guessing that you're trying to do something like this instead:

```
@chocolate = Chocolate.includes(:kinds).find(params[:chocolate_id])
```

Then you are querying the database for the `Chocolate` and associated `Kind` records instead of trying to instantiate a new record.

Comment: ah, I see! But in that case it gives me `Couldn't find Chocolate without an ID`. But I send it ID via `:chocolate_id`. No?

Comment: What does your route look like? Perhaps the ID is available at `params[:id]`? I cannot guess that for you.